# Custom Library cannot open source files of Dependencies such as SDL2 & Box2D

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

I have been working on creating my own game framework and recently have been trying to figuring out how to compile it as a library using CMake. However, I have ran into an issue that I cannot figure out. When trying to use the lib file created by CMake errors pop up saying that it cannot open a library, for example "**Severity Code Description   Project File Line Suppression State Error (active) E1696    cannot open source file 'SDL2/SDL.h' Test F:\Code\MyProject\include\App.h 7**". I believed this was caused by the dependencies not being exported with the framework. Also just in case it helps I used Vcpkg to get my libraries.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)

set(PROJECT_NAME MyProject)

set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)

if(NOT DEFINED CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE)
    set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "vcpkg/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake"
    CACHE STRING "")
    message(" [INFO] VCPKG CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE = ${CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE}")
endif()

project(${PROJECT_NAME} VERSION 1.0.0)

find_package(SDL2 CONFIG REQUIRED)
message(" [INFO] Found SDL2")
find_package(sdl2-image CONFIG REQUIRED)
message(" [INFO] Found SDL2-Image")
find_package(sdl2-mixer CONFIG REQUIRED)
message(" [INFO] Found SDL2-Mixer")
find_package(sdl2-ttf CONFIG REQUIRED)
message(" [INFO] Found SDL2-TTF")
find_package(unofficial-box2d CONFIG REQUIRED)
message(" [INFO] Found Box2D")

file(GLOB SOURCES "include/*h" "include/*.cpp")

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} STATIC ${SOURCES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2 SDL2::SDL2main PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2_image PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2_mixer PRIVATE SDL2::SDL2_ttf PRIVATE unofficial::box2d::box2d )

set_target_properties( ${PROJECT_NAME}
    PROPERTIES
    ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib"
    LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib"
    RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/bin"
)
```

Comment: Please, add **exact error message** into the question post, which includes, among other things, location of the error.

Comment: Error says you are missing headers. You need to add correct `target_include_directories`, which contain missing headers.

Comment: Well when I made it as an executable the program ran fine it was only after swapping it to a library that it started to fail. Do I still need to include_directories?

Comment: Is this CMake file for your framework or a library that uses it?

Comment: It is for my framework that has depends on some external libraries